# Azure DevOps Gradle "Java heap space" error

Tags: android, azure, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using an Azure DevOps Pipeline for CI/CD for a ReactNative Android app.

It has been working great for a while now, but in my latest release the Gradle build is running into the following error:

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signProductionReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > Java heap space
```

The relevant part of my `azure-pipelines.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: "macos-latest" # I am using this image because I am also doing iOS builds (not sure if it's relevant to the problem)

jobs:
  - job: DeployAndroid
    steps:
      - task: Gradle@2
        inputs:
          gradleWrapperFile: "MyApp/android/gradlew"
          cwd: "MyApp/android"
          tasks: "bundleProductionRelease"
          publishJUnitResults: false
          javaHomeOption: "JDKVersion"
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

`Java heap space` isn't a very descriptive error, but it seems reasonable to assume it is a memory issue. I attempted to increase the max JVM memory by adding the [gradleOptions argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops#arguments):

```yaml
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleOptions: "-Xmx3072m"
```

The default value is `-Xmx1024m`, so I thought tripling the memory (`-Xmx3072m`) might work. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered there were several problems that needed to solved to get this to work.

For some reason the `gradleOptions` argument in `azure-pipelines.yml` wasn't increasing the memory, even though the documentation shows it being used specifically for the `-Xmx` flag. (I imagine something about my setup is just overriding it)

Instead I added the following line to my `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx10240m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I found that the MacOS Azure images have the following [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#hardware):

```
Mac pros with a 3 core CPU, 14 GB of RAM, and 14 GB of SSD disk space
```

So, I set the `Xmx` flag (max JVM heap memory size) to a relatively high 10GB (`10240m`).

I don't actually know what `XX:MaxPermSize` does, but it is also related to memory. The other flags are just related to debugging.

---

This ended up only being half of my problem, but the other half isn't particularly relevant to my original question.

I originally placed all the blame on Azure, but I realized that I had only run the debug bundle locally, and the production bundle was also failing with the same error on my local machine.

My other problem was specific to `React Native`. It resulted in the same error though, so I imagine both are somehow related.

The issue was that I had upgraded to a more recent version of React Native, but missed some of the changes that had been made to `android/app/build.gradle`.

I doubt the specifics of what I happened to be missing would be very helpful to anyone, but if you run into this error, I suggest you check the [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) to see if you're missing anything in your `build.gradle` file.